# Stochastic matrices for continuous-time linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stochastic-matrices

If matrices are stochastic (row stochastic) or doubly/bistochastic, we can make claims about the behavior of the discrete-time dynamical systems they represent. For example:

- discrete-time Markov chains always converge to a steady-state distributions.
- bistochastic systems converge to consensus states.

Does this intuition change when dealing with continuous-time linear systems? Or is there an analogous property that is required for continuous linear systems to converge in this way?

Comment: Do you mean $\dot x = A x$ with stochastic $A$?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: You get $e^t$ along vector $\Bbb 1$, which is kind of nonsense.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you explain that a little more?

Comment: If $A$ is stochastic (rows sum to $1$) then $\Bbb 1$ is a (right) eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. Hence, $e^{t A}$ has eigenpair $(e^t, \Bbb 1)$. Another question: given sampling period $h$, for which matrices $A$ is the matrix exponential $\exp(h A)$ stochastic?